# html.xpath("//text()") in lxml

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, lxml

I am reading lxml tutorial with the following demonstration:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC ipython :session lxml :results output
print(html.xpath("string()")) # lxml.etree only!
# TEXTTAIL
print(html.xpath("//text()")) # lxml.etree only!
#  ['TEXT', 'TAIL']
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: TEXTTAIL
: ['TEXT', 'TAIL']
```

I am confused with the `//`in `html.xpath("//text()"`

If removed them thus get a empty list returned.

```
#+begin_src ipython :session lxml :results output
print(html.xpath("text()"))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: []
```

Comment: Did my answer help or are you still confused?

Answer (score 1):

From the [XPath 1.0 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#path-abbrev):

> // is short for /descendant-or-self::node()/. For example, //para is
>   short for /descendant-or-self::node()/child::para and so will select
>   any para element in the document (even a para element that is a
>   document element will be selected by //para since the document element
>   node is a child of the root node); div//para is short for
>   div/descendant-or-self::node()/child::para and so will select all para
>   descendants of div children.

So `//text()` is equivalent to `/descendant-or-self::node()/child::text()` which will select all text nodes in the document.

When you remove the `//`, you're only selecting text nodes that are children of the current context (whatever `html` is).